# Angular asp.net RedirectToAction

Tags: angularjs, model-view-controller, angular-ui-router

I'm working with angular and asp.net, everrytime a page is called the server checks if the user is logged in, I user the RedirectToAction() method to redirect to the login page.
So if the user navigates to the state "overview" and he isn't logged in, but till this point the overview state always shows the login page, till there is a completed refresh.
Is there any solution for this?

Comment: I don't think so the state 'overview' has an templateUrl which is pointing to a asp-controller, so the controller decides, which view will be shown by this state, but it seems, that the state loads the view only on the first time, and than the state will keep this view.

Answer (score 0):

Use Authrorize attribute in your actions, so it will redirect automatically to login page if user is not logged it.

```
[Authorize]
public ActionResult Index()
{
    ViewBag.AppName = "YourApp";
    return View();
}
```